# Repair ubuntu 19.10 on raspberry pi

Tags: boot, upgrade, ubuntu-mate, sd-card, raspberrypi

I'm using ubuntu server 19.10 on a raspberry pi 4, and my system is installed on a micro SD card.
Yesterday I tried to upgrade ubuntu from 19.10 to 20.04 by using `sudo do-release-upgrade`.
After a few minutes a black screen with only a blinking cursor appeared, and stayed for multiple hours. At a certain point I unplugged, thinking it crashed.
When I restarted everything worked fine, and a mate session started, because I log in automatically.
There was no panel, no icons, and the wallpaper was replaced with a gradation from blue to green.
I have a mate terminal desktop launcher so I double clicked on it. Then I realized my keyboard wasn't working anymore, so it was useless. The right click also don't work so I can't access any menu.
I tried to hold `Shift` , `Escape` and `Menu` when booting but nothing happened.
How can I recover from this? I also have another SD card with raspbian on it, so I certainly can use it to repair ubuntu, if possible.